# Nesting dropdown sidebar menu items in Laravel Backpack

Tags: php

I'm new to Laravel BackPack.

I would like to create a submenu one level below within the sidebar menu, but I am unable to do so.
As you can see from the document below,
nested = "true"
I heard that adding this attribute makes it possible, is that true?

[document](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/base-components#menu-dropdown-menu-dropdown-item)

The submenu seems to work in the Live demo.
However, I cannot create it in my environment.
If there's any information I've missed, please let me know.

Below is my source code.
When executed, submenu2 does not exist in menu1.
submenu2 exists at the same level as menu1

resources/views/vendor/backpack/ui/inc/menu_items.blade.php

```
{{-- This file is used for menu items by any Backpack v6 theme --}}
<x-backpack::menu-item title="{{ trans('backpack::base.dashboard') }}" icon="la la-dashboard" :link="backpack_url('dashboard')" />

<x-backpack::menu-dropdown title="menu1" icon="la la-group">
    <x-backpack::menu-dropdown-item title="submenu1" icon="la la-question" :link="backpack_url('submenu1')" />
    <x-backpack::menu-dropdown title="submenu2" icon="la la-group" nested="true">
        <x-backpack::menu-dropdown-item title="nest-submenu1" icon="la la-user" :link="backpack_url('nest-submenu1')" />
        <x-backpack::menu-dropdown-item title="nest-submenu2" icon="la la-user" :link="backpack_url('nest-submenu2')" />
        <x-backpack::menu-dropdown-item title="nest-submenu3" icon="la la-user" :link="backpack_url('nest-submenu3')" />
    </x-backpack::menu-dropdown>
</x-backpack::menu-dropdown>
```

#### PHP VERSION:

PHP 8.1.23

#### LARAVEL VERSION:

10.13.5.0

#### BACKPACK PACKAGE VERSIONS:

backpack/basset: 1.0.2
backpack/crud: 6.1.2
backpack/editable-columns: 3.0.2
backpack/generators: v4.0.2
backpack/pro: 2.0.18
backpack/theme-tabler: 1.0.11